# The limit of inverse trigonometry function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

What is the value of
$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} (\arctan (n+1) - \arctan (n))? $

I have opened my old notes about manipulating trigonometry function in limit form, but don't have much experience in its inverses like this. This is a real analysis problem and maybe need some theorems to emphasize the understandings.

Comment: You know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\arctan n=\pi/2$ surely?

Comment: OMG, I realized that now.. Btw, how about $\arcsin x$ and $\arccos x$?

Comment: What is $\arcsin n$ for $n>1$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \arctan x=\pi/2.
$$

Comment: And the limit of $\arctan (x+1)$ is also $\pi/2$?

Comment: Yes the limit in that case is also $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

You could try it the other way around.

$$\arctan (n+1)-\arctan n=\arctan \left(\frac {1}{n^2+n+1}\right) $$

Hence $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \arctan (n+1)-\arctan n=\lim_{x\to\infty} \arctan \left(\frac {1}{n^2+n+1}\right) =0$$

Comment: Where do you get that equation?

Comment: @ShaneDizzySukardy Let $\alpha=\arctan (n+1)$ and $\beta=\arctan n$. Hence $\tan \alpha=(n+1)$ and $\tan \alpha=n$ and then apply the formula $$\tan(\alpha-\beta) =\left(\frac {\tan \alpha-\tan \beta}{1+\tan \alpha \tan \beta}\right) $$

Answer (score 0):

Using MVT

$$\arctan (n+1)-\arctan (n)=\frac {1}{1+c_n^2 } $$
with $$n <c_n <n+1$$

When $n \to +\infty , \; c_n\to +\infty $